# Is there a name for "co-normal" subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I have in mind a situation where a group $G$ has two subgroups $H$ and $K$ with the property that each of them is closed under conjugation by elements of the other.

More formally: for $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ then $h^{-1} k h \in K$ and $k^{-1}h k \in H$.

Is there a name for this?

Answer (score 5):

I would call them "mutually normalizing subgroups", and a Google search shows that other people have used this (which doesn't prove that there is not some more commonly used name).

Comment: This seems a more appropriate name than "co-normal". "Co-normality" sounds to me as dual to normality, and I find it confusing.

Answer (score 2):

$H$ is stable under conjugation by elements of $K$ if, and only if, $K$ is a subgroup of the normalizer $N_G(H)$ (which is the largest subgroup of $G$ which contains $H$ as a normal subgroup).

I don't think there is a name for the situation where $K\subset N_G(H)$ and $H\subset N_G(K)$.

Answer (score 2):

A brief description is that $[H,K] \leq H \cap K$.

Suppose $G$ is a group with two subgroups $H,K$.

If $H$ normalizes $K$, then $k^{-1} \left( h^{-1} k h \right) \leq KK = K$ so $[H,K] \leq K$. Conversely if $[H,K] \leq K$, then $h^{-1} k h = k \cdot \left( k^{-1} h^{-1} k h \right) \leq KK = K$, so $H$ normalizes $K$.

Switching the roles of $H$ and $K$ gives that $K$ normalizes $H$ iff $[H,K] \leq H$.

Hence $H$ and $K$ normalize each other iff $[H,K] \leq H \cap K$.

Answer (score 2):

By far the most popular according to Google is "$H$ and $K$ normalize each other".

Comment: But you were one of the authors I found by Googling “mutually normalizing subgroups”. That must count for something, surely?

Comment: @JeremyRickard It merely shows the folly of youth.

Answer (score 1):

Never seen this situation explored and don't think there's a name for it. Let's say that $(H,K)$ is a conormal pair if they satisfy the property you consider.

Two elementary observations are:

Every subgroup belongs to a conormal pair since $(K,\{e_G\})$ is conormal for every $K<G$. So, given $K$ one may ask about the (?) largest $H$ such that $(H,K)$ is conormal.

If $G=HK$ and $(H,K)$ is conormal, then both $H$ and $K$ are normal in $G$.

Comment: The largest $H$ such that $(H,K)$ is "conormal" is $H=N_G(K)$.